# Array_Shift function - parameter not by reference

Tags: php

I need to use two arrays - initial one, and the same array without the first element. For example:

```
public function foobar($a, $b, $c)
{
   $initial_array = get_defined_var();
   var_dump($initial_array); // ok
   $sliced_array = array_shift($initial_array);
   var_dump($sliced_array); // int(1) ???

   //initial array should be 'a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c
   // sliced array should be 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c
}
```

The problem is that sliced array seems to be some strange value, like int(1)...What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You can try with [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$sliced_array = array_slice($initial_array, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

array_shift modifies the original array, and return the shifted element, which is the value of $a = 1 in this case.

Comment: you should explain how to achieve what they want also, else this answer is incomplete

Comment: @SterlingArcher, I think the OP just want to know why it happened

Comment: Yes, but who goes on Main and asks why something is wrong without wanting to know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`array_shift` modifies the array it receives by removing its first element (as opposed to returning a copy of the array it receives)

If you want a copy of `initial_array` with the first element removed, try this

```
public function foobar($a, $b, $c)
{
   $initial_array = get_defined_var();      
   $sliced_array = $initial_array; //copy the array
   array_shift($sliced_array); //remove 1st element
}
```